# set search url in jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

how to set a search url in jqgrid ,i tried following by setting url in a search option but everytime jqgrid takes the url  from **url** property which i have set in a grid

```
jQuery("#myGrid").jqGrid({
                .....
        url:"/api/eventAllInfo", // using this url for search
                  ......

});
```

Settings for add ,edit and search

```
jQuery("#myGrid").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager', 

    {
    add: true,
    edit:true,
    del:true,
    search:true

    }, //options 

    {

            reloadAfterSubmit:false , 
            editurl:"/api/getMetaInfo",
            mtype:'PUT',
//         beforeShowForm: function(form) { $('#tr_e_info_id', form).hide(); }

    }, // edit options 
    {
            reloadAfterSubmit:false,
        editurl:"/api/getMetaInfo",
            mtype:'POST',
//         beforeShowForm: function(form) { $('#tr_e_info_id', form).hide(); }

    }, // add options 
    {
            reloadAfterSubmit:false,
            editurl:"/api/getMetaInfo",
    }, // del options
    {

        editurl:"/api/getMetaInfo/search",
    } // search options 


);
```

i tried searching other post but no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no `url` for the [searching dialog](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:singe_searching#options). The reason is easy. The searching will be interpreted as *filling* the grid only. For better understanding the logic which uses jqGrid I explain all together with other operations which follow *filling* or *reloading* of the grid.

The user has control which allows to choose page size

[image]

The user has another control to choose the page number: either by pressing of buttons like "Next Page", "Last Page" and so on or by entering the new page number directly:

[image]

In the same way the user can specify the searching filter in the searching dialog or in the filter toolbar (if any provided).

The user can click on the column header to change the column by which the grid will be sorted or to change the direction of the sorting:

[image]

**In all the cases** the `postData` parameter will be constructed and the parameters `page`, `rows`, `sidx`, `sord`, `_search`, `filters` will be set. **In all the cases It will be used the same `url`**, but just with additional parameters.

So there are no special "searching" URL like there are not "sorting" URL or "paging" URL. If the user apply searching filter jqGrid sets just corresponding `postData` parameters and **reloads** the grid.

Comment: so if i want to set /api/eventAllInfo/search then ?

Comment: @Hunt: Sorry, but like I described in my answer, it has not much sense. The `/api/eventAllInfo/search` should provide *full functionality* to fill the grid: sorting, paging and not only filtering. If you want support "searching" in the grid you have to extend the server code to support additional parameters like `_search` and `filters`.